# How to align divs side by side without one being slightly lower?

Tags: html, css, salesforce

Hi I'm building an app on the Salesforce1 platform and I'm having some trouble with the UI. If you look at the recent and popular ideas columns, technically they are side by side but the Recent Ideas column is slightly lower than the Popular Ideas column and I can't figure out how to get them exactly side by side again. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

HTML (ignore the apex tags. Indentation is a bit messed up because of how I had to format it to put it in a code block for this post)

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Idea" recordSetVar="idea"
sidebar="false" 
showHeader="false" 
standardstylesheets="false"
doctype="html-5.0">

<head> </head>
<body>

<apex:stylesheet value="{!$Resource.PuroIdeas_Homepage_CSS}" /> 

<div id="header">
  <a href="https://cs3.salesforce.com/apex/PuroIdeas_Home">
      <img id="PuroIdeasLogo" src="{!$Resource.PuroIdeasLogo}"/>
  </a>
  <br/>
  <p id="introCopy" >PuroIdeas is a place where you can innovate. Share your ideas, check out others, join the discussion and help build a better Purolator</p>
</div>

<div id="login">
  <p class="loginText"> Login | Sign Up </p>
</div>

<div id="Challenges">
  <h1 class="ChallengesHeader"> Challenges </h1>
  <div class="activeChallenge">
     <!--   <apex:dataList value="{!ideatheme}" var="i" id="list">
        {!i.title}
        </apex:dataList> 
      <apex:pageblock>
        <apex:outputField value="{!idea.title}" />
      </apex:pageblock> -->


  <p> CHALLENGE 1 - </p>



  </div>
  <div class="activeChallenge">
  <p> CHALLENGE 2 - </p>
  </div>
  <div class="activeChallenge">
  <p> CHALLENGE 3 - </p>
  </div>   
  <!-- Do I need a div for the view all button? -->
</div>

<div id="rpIdeasContainer">
<div id="recentIdeas">
  <h1 class="RecentIdeasHeader"> Recent Ideas </h1>
<div class="rIdeas"> Recent Idea 1</div>
<div class="rIdeas"> Recent Idea 2</div>
<div class="rIdeas"> Recent Idea 3</div>
</div>

<div id="popularIdeas">
  <h1 class="PopularIdeasHeader"> Popular Ideas </h1>
<div class="pIdeas"> Popular Idea 1</div>
<div class="pIdeas"> Popular Idea 2</div>
<div class="pIdeas"> Popular Idea 3</div>
</div>

</div>


<div id="generalFeedback">
  <h1 class="GeneralFeedbackHeader">General Feedback</h1>
  <p>Category <br/> Title <br/> Description</p>
  <apex:form >
     <!-- <apex:inputField ></apex:inputField> -->
     <!-- <apex:commandButton action="{!submit}" value="Submit"/> -->
  </apex:form> 
</div>

<div id="pastChallenges">
  <h1 class="PastChallengesHeader">Past Challenges</h1>
<div class="pChallenge"> Past Challenges 1</div>
<div class="pChallenge"> Past Challenges 2</div>
<div class="pChallenge"> Past Challenges 3</div>
</div>

<div id="ideasInAction">
  <h1 class="IdeasInActionHeader">Ideas In Action</h1>
<div class="IIA"> Idea in Action 1</div>
<div class="IIA"> Idea in Action 2</div>
<div class="IIA"> Idea in Action 3</div>
</div>

</body>

</apex:page>
```

CSS

```
#header
{
width: 70%;
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-color: #D1D1D1;
border-width: 2px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

#PuroIdeasLogo
{
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

#introCopy
{
text-align: center;
font-family: "Segoe UI"; /*Helvetica, Arial;*/
font-weight: lighter;
max-width: 60%;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
color: #575757;
}

#login
{
width: 70%;
/*border-bottom-style: solid;
border-color: #D1D1D1;
border-width: 1px;*/
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

.loginText 
{
text-align: center;
font-family: "Segoe UI", Helvetica, Arial;
font-weight: lighter;
}

#Challenges
{
width: 70%;
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-color: #D1D1D1;
border-width: 1px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto; 
}

.ChallengesHeader
{
padding-left: 40px;
font-family: "Segoe UI";
font-weight: lighter;
color: #575757;
}

.activeChallenge
{
width: 90%;
margin: 20px auto;
padding: 15px;
font-family: "Segoe UI";
font-weight: lighter;
color: #2071FE;
/*background-color: #2071FE;*/
border: 2px solid #2071FE;
border-radius: 15px;
}

#rpIdeasContainer
{
width: 70%; 
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-width: 1px;
border-color:#D1D1D1;

}

#recentIdeas
{
width: 50%;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
float:left;

}

.RecentIdeasHeader
{
padding-left: 40px;
font-family: "Segoe UI";
font-weight: lighter;
color: #575757;
}

.rIdeas
{
width: 85%;
margin: 20px auto;
border: 1px solid red;
font-family: "Segoe UI", Helvetica, Arial;
font-weight: lighter;
color: #ADADAD;
}

#popularIdeas
{
margin-left: 50%;
margin-right: auto;

}

.PopularIdeasHeader
{
padding-left: 40px;
font-family: "Segoe UI";
font-weight: lighter;
color: #575757;
}

.pIdeas
{
width: 85%;
margin: 20px auto;
border: 1px solid red;
font-family: "Segoe UI", Helvetica, Arial;
font-weight: lighter;
color: #ADADAD;
}

#generalFeedback
{
width: 70%;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
font-family: "Segoe UI", Helvetica, Arial;
font-weight: lighter;
color: #ADADAD;
}

.GeneralFeedbackHeader
{
padding-left: 40px;
font-family: "Segoe UI";
font-weight: lighter;
color: #575757;
}

#pastChallenges
{
width: 70%;
border-style: dotted;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

.PastChallengesHeader
{
padding-left: 40px;
font-family: "Segoe UI";
font-weight: lighter;
color: #575757;
}

.pChallenge
{
font-family: "Segoe UI", Helvetica, Arial;
font-weight: lighter;
color: #ADADAD;
}

#ideasInAction
{
width: 70%;
border-style: dotted;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

.IdeasInActionHeader
{
padding-left: 40px;
font-family: "Segoe UI";
font-weight: lighter;
color: #575757;
}
.IIA 
{
font-family: "Segoe UI", Helvetica, Arial;
font-weight: lighter;
color: #ADADAD;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would modify the following classes as such:

```
#recentIdeas {
    width: 48%;
    background-color: #FFA500;
    padding: 0px !important;
    margin: 0px !important;
    display: inline-block;
}
#popularIdeas {
    width: 48%;
    background-color: #AFA500;
    padding: 0px !important;
    margin: 0px !important;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

You can see this here-> http://jsfiddle.net/T2GG4/

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 2):

try to add this in the popular idea div

```
#popularIdeas
{
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

or

```
vertical-align:top;
```

what's happening?
if thats not working you can just use

```
display: inline-block
```

on both div (popular ideas and recent ideas)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest something different for the same, You can use `display` property instead of `float` property. You might have to do some changes like following

```
#recentIdeas {
   width: 50%;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   /* float: left; */ /* Removed this */
   vertical-align: top; /* Added this */
   display: inline-block; /* Added this */
}

#popularIdeas
{
    /*margin-left: 50%;*/ /* Removed this */
    margin-right: auto; 
    display:inline-block; /* Added this */
    vertical-align:top /* Added this */
}
```

### [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jrNTt/1/)

Comment: How does this answer the question? Your div's are not even aligned on the same line, forget, next to each other!!

Comment: @SatwikNadkarny Did you check the fiddle? and also please have a look at the image that OP has posted !

Comment: The two div's won't stack up next to each other when the window is resized? I have to resize the width of the window in the fiddle for the two div's to stack up.